# Define key for html email

Tags: webforms

I'm using Symfony Mailer to send HTML emails in my site.

This requires 'module' and 'key' to find my email twig template file.

How do I find or define 'key' for my email handler in my Webform settings?

Answer (score 1):

Solved after lots of experimenting.

Select 'Twig template' as the Body type in the email handler.

Name your twig file as 'webform-email-message-html--WEBFORM-ID.html.twig'.